# Reactstrap Dropdown Menu in NavBar is contained within NavBar, doesn't overlay main page

Tags: reactstrap

I am using Reactstrap.  I have a vertical NavBar in a Column with a [Dropdown](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/dropdowns/) which displays a menu to the right when clicked.

The Dropdown menu is contained within the NavBar.  Some of it is cutoff depending on how wide the NavBar is.  In fact, it covers the NavBar menu itself if the NavBar is narrow.

I would like the Drowndown menu to overlay the main page.

Amazon has a horizontal NavBar, and when you hover over the DropDown menu, it overlays over the main page.

That's the effect I want, except my NavBar is vertical.

Are there any guidelines for how I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

I had the NavBar in a "Col" on the left.  I removed the Col.